# Using mysql_fetch_row( ) to generate edit form

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I am hoping to get a function to generate an edit form from a table.
I would like to convert the Primary key to a hidden input and the rest to textboxes.
This is as far as i could get

```
function getform($table)  {
    $html= "";  
    $result = mysql_query("Select * From $table");
    if (!$result) {
       echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
       // return from function here. don't know what value you need.
       return "";
    }
    $fieldnames = array();
    $fieldCount = mysql_num_fields($result);
    for( $i=0; $i<$fieldCount; $i++ ) {
       $fieldnames[] = ucfirst(mysql_field_name( $result , $i ));
    }

);
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the primary keys and secondly the size of the feilds

Comment: use `mysqli` extension it has support to get field names built in

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements instead of the mysql_ functions, they've been deprecated.

Comment: also is $table sanitized before being passed to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you started with rather than telling you to start again, assuming you are maintaining an old application.

However if this is a new app you really shoulld invest the time to learn mysqli or PDO instead.

```
function getform($table)  {
    $html= "";  
    $result = mysql_query("Select * From $table");
    if (!$result) {
       echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
       // return from function here. don't know what value you need.
       return "";
    }

    $fieldnames = array();
    for( $i=0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++ ) {
       $t = array();
       $t['name'] = mysql_field_name( $result , $i );
       $t['type'] = mysql_field_type( $result , $i );
       $t['len'] = mysql_field_len( $result, $i );
       $t['flags'] = mysql_field_flags( $result, $i ); 

       $fieldnames[] = $t;
    }
}
```

This should produce something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ID
            [type] => int
            [len] => 5
            [flags] => not_null primary_key unique_key multiple_key unsigned auto_increment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => CallID
            [type] => int
            [len] => 7
            [flags] => multiple_key unsigned
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Complaint
            [type] => string
            [len] => 255
            [flags] => multiple_key
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Date
            [type] => date
            [len] => 10
            [flags] => multiple_key binary
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "DESCRIBE table" (where 'table' is the name of your db table) to get a description of your table, which will give you an array as follows below. Recursing through this array (user table, in my case) will give you all the information you need about the table.

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => id
                    [Type] => int(11)
                    [Null] => NO
                    [Key] => PRI
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => auto_increment
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => created
                    [Type] => int(11)
                    [Null] => NO
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => updated
                    [Type] => int(11)
                    [Null] => NO
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => enabled
                    [Type] => int(11)
                    [Null] => NO
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => email
                    [Type] => varchar(255)
                    [Null] => YES
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => password
                    [Type] => varchar(255)
                    [Null] => YES
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => username
                    [Type] => varchar(255)
                    [Null] => YES
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => name
                    [Type] => varchar(255)
                    [Null] => YES
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [Field] => surname
                    [Type] => varchar(255)
                    [Null] => YES
                    [Key] => 
                    [Default] => 
                    [Extra] => 
                )

        )

)
```